# hook_menu_alter information

Tags: hooks

I am using drupal 6.22.

I have written a framework module that relies on submodules, when I install the submodule, I would like to update the administration menu to include some administration properties for the submodule.

This is the hook_menu implementation on the framework and it works no problem:

```
function svm_mail_menu() {

$items['admin/settings/svm-mail'] = array(
  'title' => 'SeeViewMedia Mailing Framework',
  'description' => 'Framework Settings for the SeeViewMedia Mailing application',
  'page callback' => 'mail_settings', //this needs to direct to a tabbed page that holds the framework options such as general settings and account add/edit/delete
  //This page should also be a "welcome" page for the module listing where everything is found
  //'access arguments' => array('Administer SeeViewMedia Framework Settings'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
$items['admin/settings/svm-mail/add-account'] = array(
'title' => 'Add Mailing Account',
'page callback' => 'add_mail_account',
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,  
);
$items['admin/settings/svm-mail/view-accounts'] = array(
  'title' => 'View Mailing Accounts',
  'page callback' => 'view_mail_account',
  'access arguments' => array('Administer SeeViewMedia Framework Settings'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
return $items;
}
```

and this is the hook_menu_alter that I tried using, but it replaces my entire menu system

```
function ymlp_svm_mail_menu_alter(&$items) {
$items = svm_mail_menu();

$items['admin/settings/ymlp-svm-mail/update'] = array(
  'title' => 'Update YMLP Accounts Manually',
  'page callback' => 'ymlp_update',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
return $items;
}
```

How would I just add this little bit of menu to the original menu that I created without destroying everything else?

Comment: If you are not trying to replace an existing menu, you should not use `hook_menu_alter()`. In your case, if you are adding an "update" menu item, then you should use `hook_menu()` because there isn't an "update" menu item that you are trying to change.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, to me; a module can extend the menu defined from another one. That is not different from defining a menu item for a menu that has not been defined from another module.

Answer (score 3):

If all you are doing is *adding* to an existing menu, there is no need to use a menu alter. Instead stick with plain old hook_menu().

```
function ymlp_svm_mail_menu() {
  $items['admin/settings/ymlp-svm-mail/update'] = array(
    'title' => 'Update YMLP Accounts Manually',
    'page callback' => 'ymlp_update',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Don't forget to flush the menu cache after the module is installed

Comment: I tried exactly what you have suggested here, but this has caused my original menu to disappear and added the new menu :(
I also cleared the cache as you suggested, but no change :(

Comment: SOLUTION:

This was a little silly of me, but the answer lies within the assigned url:

This is the primary menu Item url:

    $items['admin/settings/svm-mail']

This where I was directing to:

    $items['admin/settings/ymlp-svm-mail/update']

In the end I changed it to this

    $items['admin/settings/svm-mail/view-accounts']

and now it works as I needed it to work.
It was a simple logical misunderstanding, but hopefully someone in the future can use this.

Thanks to @wiifm for leading me to the answer.